# ERROR in Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct {
    char unit1[3];  // unit1 has value ns
    char unit2[3];  // unit2 has value ns
    char unit3[3];  // unit3 has value ns
} unit;

unit u;
```

I have one global structure and it has 3 character array of size 3 and has value "ns\0" in it. Null terminated hence size 3.

```
/* This function checks if all has same unit */
int check_conversion_unit() {
    if ( (u.unit1[0] == u.unit2[0]) && (u.unit2[0] == u.unit3[0]))     // ERROR HERE
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

Some other function calls this function to check if all unit has same size or not before doing calculation. But, When I try to compile this code, I am getting an error as follows:

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

Comment: Did you forget a `typedef`?

Comment: `if` is missing a bracket

Comment: No it was typo while typing question

Answer (score 3):

You forget `)` here:

```
if ( (u.unit1[0] == u.unit2[0]) && (u.unit2[0] == u.unit3[0]) )  
//                                                            ^
//                                                            | that's one
```

Comment: not ) ..it was typo while typing question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but it was the first what I see when I reformat your code. May be you can post directly your code. As I see your have a lot of typos mistakes in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is wrong `struct` declaration..

It should be like this

```
struct unit {
    char unit1[3];  // unit1 has value ns
    char unit2[3];  // unit2 has value ns
    char unit3[3];  // unit3 has value ns
};
```

Then you have to declare like this

> struct unit u;

Or if you want to typedef,

```
typedef struct {
    char unit1[3];  // unit1 has value ns
    char unit2[3];  // unit2 has value ns
    char unit3[3];  // unit3 has value ns
} unit;
```

Then you can directly use it

> unit u;

Comment: not this..it was typo while typing question. Thanks